# The Closing of How can Santa exist when adults buy the toys?

Tags: discussion

[How can Santa exist when adults buy the toys?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13495/how-can-santa-exist-when-adults-buy-the-toys)

Why was this seen as off-topic?
Is world-building reserved for subject matter suitable to an adult audience?

If the OP (who is not me) is a children's author, looking for a plausible explanation for the weird behavior of parents in their Santa-is-real Children's story...   How is that not world-building?

*I do not know the OP, nor do I know that the OP is a children's author.  I'm involved here only in self-interest: I wrote a really cool answer and the question got closed moments before I could post it.  At first, I posted my answer as three-successive comments, then I thought better and deleted those comments so that I could bring the discussion here*

Comment: The question has now been reopened.

Comment: @HDE226868 I would suggest that you add that as an answer (separate from your existing answer) so that it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I was the second to vote to close, so I'll voice my rationale.

The question, as phrased, seemed - and still seems, so some extent - to me to be more a reflection on *our* world, not a built world. The title itself, "How *can* . . ." (emphasis mine) is also along the lines of, "This is a commentary on our world." At least, that's how it seemed to me.

For what it's worth, I voted to close not as off-topic but as unclear - which sucks, because the close message indicates that I thought it was off-topic. I thought it was on-topic, I just didn't understand it, because it seemed like the heart of it wasn't as prominently placed.

As for my rationale for voting to reopen. . .

> Is world-building reserved for subject matter suitable to an adult audience?

*(Cough cough) Awkward moment.* Funny, how I'm a kid voicing my opinion here.

There wasn't really much wrong with the question, looking back. [Bret called it "rambling"](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13495/how-can-santa-exist-when-adults-buy-the-toys#comment32358_13495), and tried to fix that a bit. It just seemed a bit confusing. But I think it's all right because it discusses a societal aspect. We've had . . . erm . . . controversial questions regarding in-world beliefs, and they're on-topic. The beliefs discussed here are simply different. And they aren't beliefs, come to think of it.

I for one look forward to seeing your answer, should the question be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

I'm leaning towards a reopen now that it has been changed, even though the change is small.  It feels on-topic enough for me.  He gave clear definitions of what he wanted out of santa-clause world, and expressed what he thought made it difficult to implement.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Michael's comment](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1955/the-closing-of-how-can-santa-exist-when-adults-buy-the-toys#comment4349_1955) . . .

The question has now been re-opened. And Henry has added [his answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13495/how-can-santa-exist-when-adults-buy-the-toys/13521#13521), which has turned out to be very good.